Azure.Core.ClientInfo tries to target wrong version of dependancy System.Memory
I am trying to send an email from my application.
Here is my code:
Public Shared Async Function SendErrorEmail(subject As String, _Body As String, MailTo As String) As Task

            Dim scopes As String() = {"https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"}

            Dim tenantId As String = "MYID"           ' Replace with your Tenant ID
            Dim clientId As String = "MYID"           ' Replace with Application ID from Overview tab
            Dim clientSecret As String = "MYID"    ' Replace with the Client Secret

            ' Using Azure.Identity;
            Dim options As New Azure.Identity.TokenCredentialOptions With {
                .AuthorityHost = Azure.Identity.AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
            }

            Dim clientSecretCredential As New ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options)

            Dim graphClient As GraphServiceClient = New GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes)


            Dim ToList As New List(Of Recipient)

            ToList.Add(New Recipient With {.EmailAddress = New EmailAddress With {.Address = "MYEMAIL"}})


            Dim message As New Microsoft.Graph.Models.Message With {
                .Subject = subject,
                .Body = New ItemBody With {
                    .ContentType = BodyType.Html,
                    .Content = _Body
                },
                .ToRecipients = ToList
            }

            Dim Body As New Microsoft.Graph.Users.Item.SendMail.SendMailPostRequestBody With {
                .Message = message,
                .SaveToSentItems = False
            }

            Try
                Await graphClient.Users("d02b3b1a-ed44-4536-9c67-6508560fb567").SendMail.PostAsync(Body)
            Catch e As Exception
                Throw New Exception(e.Message)
            End Try

        End Function

This part throws the error
' Using Azure.Identity;
            Dim options As New Azure.Identity.TokenCredentialOptions With {
                .AuthorityHost = Azure.Identity.AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
            }

Here is the error

The type initializer for Azure.Core.ClientOptions threw an exception.
Could not load file or assembly System.Memory, Version=4.0.1.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51 or any of its dependencies. The manifest definition of the found assembly does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I have version 4.0.1.2 installed which is also the dependency but for some reason it calls for the wrong version.
I was expecting for my code to send an email. Which it didn't do.
